# Mudar option do select conforme URL

Tags: php, jquery

Eu tenho um `select` com cinco `option`. Eu quero que ele verifique o link que o usuário está e conforme esse link, ele seleciona uma opção.

Meu HTML:

```html
<select name="segmento" id="segmento" class="basic">
  <option value="">Segmento</option>
  <option value="Teste Engenharia">Teste Engenharia</option>
  <option value="Teste Hospitalar">Teste Hospitalar</option>
  <option value="Teste Ilumina&ccedil;&atilde;o">Teste Ilumina&ccedil;&atilde;o</option>
  <option value="Teste Elevadores">Teste Elevadores</option>
</select>
```

Estou tentando fazer via PHP com `preg_match`, mas meus conhecimentos são limitados, então provavelmente estou fazendo algo errado.

O que estou tentando fazer:

```html
<option
<?php 
if (preg_match( '/segmentos\/teste-hospitalar/',$database->parametros['menuRoteador']))
    echo 'value="teste Hospitalar" Teste Hospitalar';
elseif (preg_match('/segmentos\/neomot-elevadores/',$database->parametros['menuRoteador']))
    echo 'value="Teste Elevadores" Teste Elevadores';
elseif (preg_match('/segmentos\/neomot-engenharia/',$database->parametros['menuRoteador']))
    echo 'value="Teste Engenharia" Teste Engenharia';
?>
>
</option>
```

Ele deveria estar ocupado o valor do `<option value="">Segmento</option>`, mas isso não está acontecendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode melhorar sua lógica, mas acredito que o seu erro seja apenas nos `echo`s, pois você está esquecendo o caracter `>` da tag `option`.

Por exemplo este `echo`:

```
value="teste Hospitalar" Teste Hospitalar
```

Deveria estar assim:

```
value="teste Hospitalar">Teste Hospitalar
```

---

Uma alternativa para simplificar a visualização do código é assim:

```
<?php 
if (preg_match( '/segmentos\/teste-hospitalar/',$database->parametros['menuRoteador']))
    $valor = 'teste Hospitalar';
elseif (preg_match('/segmentos\/neomot-elevadores/',$database->parametros['menuRoteador']))
    $valor = 'Teste Elevadores';
elseif (preg_match('/segmentos\/neomot-engenharia/',$database->parametros['menuRoteador']))
    $valor = 'Teste Engenharia';
?>
<option value="<?= $valor ?>"><?= $valor ?></option>
```

Comment: Mas o `option` é fechado no final do PHP

Comment: @FelipeStoker Sim, você está fechando o `option`, mas está esquecendo de fechar a tag de **início** do `option`. Veja como está ficando `<option value="teste Hospitalar" teste Hospitalar></option>`. Para o browser o `option` possui 3 attributos: `value`, `teste` e `Hospitalar`.

Comment: Ahh entendi. Você está certo. O problema é que no select ficou assim `Teste Elevadores>`, ficou um `>` depois.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Sobrou um `>` depois e faltou um antes =)

Comment: na verdade eu já tinha feito a modificação que você falou, olha aqui como está http://jsfiddle.net/o3y7yj3t/

Comment: funcionou :D só achei estranho que o fechamento do `option` ficou verde http://prntscr.com/61cinw

Comment: Mude sua lógica, remova todo o código php de dentro do option e atribua o valor a uma variavel, então no select vc coloca essa variavel no value e no texto de exibição. Irá deixar o código mais legível.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Vai ficar estranho mesmo na sua IDE porque ela não vai conseguir identificar o fechamento da tag de início da option. Adicionei uma alternativa na resposta para que sua IDE identifique corretamente o código e ainda fique mais fácil de interpretar o mesmo.

Comment: Perfeito, entendi a sua explicação! :)